# Добавить src после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть `iframe`.
Хочу сделать чтобы изначально `src` был пуст, а после полной загрузки страницы добавить значение атрибута `data-src` в `src`.
Код который есть сейчас, добавляет всем одинаковую ссылку
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Glog/ha0s9gho/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('iframe').forEach(a => {
    a.setAttribute('src', a.dataset.src);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.iframe').each(function() {
    var dataSrc = $(this).attr('data-src')
   $(this).attr('src', dataSrc)
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Glog/ha0s9gho/2/)